# JAVA read multiple pictures from a file

Tags: java, java-io

Can you help me to load or read multiple images from a file. Because I know read them but How to read single file from a file but how to read multiple images. And I do not know how I would download them all from a specific folder.

For example:

// Atributes

```
protected BufferedImage imag1;
protected BufferedImage imag2;
protected BufferedImage imag3;
protected BufferedImage imag4;

//Konstructor

public GeneralTurtle(JFrame myForm) 
{
    poc =0;
    this.myForm=myForm;
    color= Color.BLACK;

    try //loading images from file turtles
    {
    imag1 = ImageIO.read(new File("hore.png"));
    imag2 = ImageIO.read(new File("dole.png"));
    imag3 = ImageIO.read(new File("vlavo.png"));
    imag4 = ImageIO.read(new File("vpravo.png"));
```

But I do not know how I would solve it better when I have more pictures. Because this would be laborious and inefficient.

It is written in NetBeans

Comment: could you tell me the file from which your are going to load images? Example pdf,ms-word etc...

Comment: This question shows no research effort. Please improve it.

Comment: In the folder named pictures. I have a sequence of seventeen images are GIF. What you need to load them so that I could work further.

Comment: If you know how to read a single image, **do it in a loop: problem solved.** There is no question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you say you have a folder....

You can do this:

```
File path = new File("MyFilesFolder");
List imageCollection = new ArrayList();
File [] files = path.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    if (files[i].isFile()){ //this line weeds out other directories/folders
        imageCollection.add(loadImage(files[i]));
    }
}
```

For the images you can use some Collection to load them in.

I take the assumption that you can work out the loadImage(File file) method.
And if you have other files then images in that folder you better read up on FileFilter.